# How to factory reset PS4 without a dualshock controller?

Tags: ps4

I have a PS5 and am looking to factory reset my PS4. However, I don't have a dualshock controller, only an @play wired controller. I booted the PS4 into safe mode and the controller worked there, but when I went to factory reset it and it says "Press PS button" it does not do anything. I also tried a USB keyboard.

Is there anyway I can get around this?